Fairy fantasy book about magic based on a points system?
I remember checking out a book from my library maybe 5-10 years ago. It was a hardcover purple and white book that might have had a pair of wings on the cover. I can’t remember the title. (It might have just been the word fairies/faeries but that is so not helpful.)
What I do remember is the book center on the female fairy in a world where the fairy folk are able to use magic but are limited in what they can do. I think everyone was born with a certain amount of magic and I think it was all based on a points system. So you’re born with X amount of points and every time you use magic it takes a specific amount of points away from your total. Once you run out of points you have no more magic.
The amount of magic everyone had carried but the main girl the book was focused on was surprised to learn she had a near infinite amount of magic she could access. I don’t remember much more than that but there had to be dramatics concerning this and the higher ups trying to control her or take her points/magic.

This is an extremely common trope.
